# Idiomatic F# un-pairwise?

Tags: f#, sequence

We can go from `seq<float>` to `seq<float * float>` with `Seq.pairwise`.

But given a sequence of homogeneous tuples, how do I get back to a sequence?

I considered

```
someSeq |> Seq.map (fun a b -> seq { yield a; yield b })
```

But that gives me the signature

```
seq<float * float> -> seq<(float * float -> seq<float * float>)>
```

I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Do you mean to undo the pairwise function?  If so, you can't just yield the tuples' members, because pairwise repeats the second member of each tuple as the first member of the subsequent tuple.  That is, `Seq.pairwise { 1 .. 5 }` gets you `val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 5)]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case a sequence expression would be more idiomatic.

```
seq { for x, y in someSeq do yield x; yield y }
```

Your function is taking two arguments instead of a single tuple.  Only one argument is passed into this lambda function but since it expects two, it returns a new function that takes the missing argument.

```
someSeq |> Seq.map(fun (a, b) -> seq { yield a; yield b })
```

This gives `<seq<seq<float>>`.  You can get to `seq<float>` with `Seq.concat`.

```
someSeq |> Seq.map(fun (a, b) -> seq { yield a; yield b }) |> Seq.concat
```

There is also `Seq.collect` which combines `Seq.map` and `Seq.concat`.

```
someSeq |> Seq.collect(fun (a, b) -> seq { yield a; yield b })
```

Here's a snip from the MSDN F# documentation about passing partial arguments to a function.

> [Partial Application of Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233229%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
>
> If you supply fewer than the specified number of arguments, you create
> a new function that expects the remaining arguments. This method of
> handling arguments is referred to as currying and is a characteristic
> of functional programming languages like F#.

Comment: I think he wants `seq<float>` not `seq<seq<float>>`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining `collect`, makes much more sense than the MSDN page!

Answer (score 5):

Try using [`Seq.collect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340468.aspx) and taking a tuple as a parameter:

```
someSeq |> Seq.collect (fun (a, b) -> seq { yield a; yield b })
```

Or as *Daniel* notes:

```
someSeq |> Seq.collect (fun (a, b) -> [a; b])
```

But note, this isn't quite the same as an 'un-pairwise', because [`Seq.pairwise`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370361.aspx) will produce one element for each adjacent pair of elements in the original list. Notice:

```
let a = [1..5]
let b = a |> Seq.pairwise
let c = b |> Seq.collect (fun (a, b) -> [a; b])

// c = [1; 2; 2; 3; 3; 4; 4; 5]
```

To truly 'un-pairwise' a pairwise sequence, you can do something like this (accepts and returns a `seq`):

```
let unpairwise (x) = 
    seq {
        if not(Seq.isEmpty x) then
            let (a, b) = Seq.head x
            yield a
            yield b
            yield! Seq.skip 1 x |> Seq.map (fun (a, b) -> b)
    }
```

Or like this (accepts a `seq`, but returns a `list`):

```
let unpairwise (x) = 
    if Seq.isEmpty x then
        []
    else
        let (a, b) = Seq.head x
        [ a; b ] @ [ for (a, b) in Seq.skip 1 x -> b ]
```

Or perhaps even like this (accepts and returns a `list`):

```
let unpairwise (x) = 
    match x with
    | (a,b)::t -> [ a; b ] @ [ for (a, b) in t -> b ]
    | _ -> []
```

Comment: How about `fun (a, b) -> [a; b]`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have meant to take `a b` as a tuple with `(a, b)`? Otherwise, `a` is the tuple and you're partially applying; mapping to a sequence of functions expecting another tuple (hence the `float * float -> seq<float * float>` signature). Very confusing!

Then you may want to flatten the sequence of sequences with `Seq.concat` or use `Seq.collect` rather than `map` to begin with.

Does that do what you wanted? That's still not exactly the inverse of `Seq.pairwise`. Not sure if that's what you were going for...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert a pairwise structure to the original list, why not just

```
let unpairwise (s: seq<'a * 'a>) : seq<'a> = seq {
  yield  (fst (Seq.head s))
  yield! (s |> Seq.map snd)
}
```

Example:

```
let pw = Seq.pairwise { 1 .. 5 } //seq [(1, 2); (2, 3); (3, 4); (4, 5)]
let up = unpairwise pw |> Seq.toList //[ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5 ]
```